# Retrieving clicked drop-down item using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pug

How would I retrieve the value of a drop-down button, positioned to the right of a text-box, using Bootstrap and JQuery?

For example, clicking "Add" would recognize it was the 'Add' drop-down item that was clicked, rather than "Remove".

I've tried the usual methods of selecting the element, but no luck, and scouring the documentation hasn't provided any luck.

Pug template:

```
.form-group
   label.col-md-4.control-label(for='addRemoveUsers') Label
   .col-md-4
     .input-group
       input#addRemoveUsers.form-control(name='buttondropdown', placeholder='', type='text')
         .input-group-btn
         button.btn.btn-default.dropdown-toggle(type='button', name="actionButton", data-toggle='dropdown')
                                    | Action
                                    span.caret
                                ul.dropdown-menu.pull-right
                                    li
                                        a(href='#', name="addUser", id="addUser") Add
                                    li
                                        a(href='#'), name="removeUser", id="removeUser") Remove
                                span.help-block Help message.
```

JQuery:

```
jQuery("#addUser").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Not working
    console.log($('#actionButton').selected())
```

Comment: I have no idea of pug, but I believe that you didn't put the id attribute to the element "actionButton", this means that when you are trying to get it with jquery it cannot find it. Because you just add the "name" attribute. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
console.log($('#actionButton').selected())
```

With

```
console.log($('#actionButton :selected').text());
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `.val()` instead of `.text()`? OP asked for "the value".